# Array of int at the output of a mex file

Tags: matlab, int, mex

I am trying to create a mex function whose entry is an integer and whose output is an array of integer. 
So the function looks like: int *myFunction(unsigned int N).
In the mexFunction, I declare a variable *variab of type int and then

```
N = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);

  /* assign a pointer to the output */
  siz= 2*ceil(log(1.0*N)/log(2.0)-0.5)+1;
  plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,siz, mxREAL);
  vari = (int*) mxGetPr(plhs[0]); */
  /* Call the subroutine. */
  vari = myFunction(N);
  mexPrintf("The first value is %d\n", vari[0]);
```

The thing is the first value is the correct one (and the other ones were checked and were correct as well) but when I call the routine mxFunction(16), I get only 0's as output. 
I guess it is because my output is an array of int but I don't know how to solve the problem. Any hint?
Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Matlab deals with doubles by default. You can easily cast them in your mex function like the following example based on your code snippet. I have made a myFunction that performs a demo algorithm. Rather than return a data type, I make it a void function and pass it a pointer to the output so that it can populate it . . .

```
/*************************************************************************/
/* Header(s)                                                             */
/*************************************************************************/
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"


/*************************************************************************/
/*the fabled myFunction                                                  */
/*************************************************************************/
void myFunction(unsigned int N, unsigned int siz, double* output)
{
    int sign = 1;
    for(int ii=0; ii<siz; ++ii)
    {
        output[ii] = (double)(ii * sign + N);
        sign *= -1;
    }

}


/*************************************************************************/
/* Gateway function and error checking                                   */
/*************************************************************************/
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  /* variable declarations */
  unsigned int siz;
  double N;

  /*  check the number of input and output parameters  */  
    if(nrhs!=1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("One input arg expected");
    if(nlhs > 1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many outputs");

  N = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);

  /* assign a pointer to the output */  
  siz= 2*ceil(log(1.0*N)/log(2.0)-0.5)+1;
  plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,siz, mxREAL);
  myFunction(N, siz, mxGetPr( plhs[0]) );
}
```

Comment: +1 But since the OP wants an integer array he should use `mxCreateNumericArray` or `mxCreateNumericMatrix` with the appropriate `mxClassID` (for eg. `mxINT32_CLASS`) to create the array. Then use `mxGetData` to get a pointer to the beginning of the array.

Comment: Fair point, but the OP didn't provide any Matlab code to accompany their question to make the requirements crystal clear. Best to err on the side of caution until they complain that it doesn't work :)